# Calling An.aspx File Into Another .aspx File

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an `asp.net` website and I want to know if its possible to call an `.aspx` file into another `.aspx` file.  The scenario is that I have 3 left hand menus which are displayed on various pages.

At first I only had one left hand menu so this was added it to my `Site.Master` file but now I have and additional 2 left hand menus and rather than keep duplicating the code for these menu's in each relevant page, I want to know if there is a way I can create them and then call the relevant menu when the page loads.

I could add each menu to my `Site.Master` and look for a specific word in my URL but this would add a lot of code to my `Site.Master` file which I'm not keen on as it will look messy.

If it can be done, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ASP.NET User Control` to achieve this. We have something similar where we've got a left menu on multple pages. Therefore what you will have to do is create the menu on the `User Control` and then use that control on each `aspx` page as required.  Regirster the control at the top of `aspx` page as

```
<%@ Register Src="~/PathTo/SomeMenu.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="SomeMenu" %>
```

And then use it as

```
<uc1:SomeMenu runat="server" ID="SomeMenu" />
```

Further reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

yo can achieve this by using [ASP.NET User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx)

or

You can Use [IFRAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328034.aspx)

```
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe" src="some.aspx" width="400px" height="400px" runat =server></iframe>
```